# Merge 2 table, if the ID is new then create a new row

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first table

[image]

My second one:
[image]

And Now I'd like to get "Value 1,2,3" from table 1 to table 2. 
"Why don't you use a simple VLOOKUP function?"

Because when there is an unused ID, i need it in a new row of my table number 2.

This is the final result I'm looking for:

[image]

I don't know if I can do it with a function, maybe a custom one?... Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So use the vlookup in table 2 against table 1.  Delete all the entries in table2 which are found in table 1.  then copy table1 into table 2.  No Duplicates and all values from table 1 will be in table 2.

Comment: Thank you for your care. But I forgot to tell I need it to be automatic and I don't know how to check entries "wich are found in table1" and wich are not.

Comment: Step 1) Add column to table 2 Step 2) add vlookup to table 2 refrerencing table 1  Step 3) Fill series down.  Step 4) add filter for not blank on vlookup Step 5) delete filtered results step 6) remove filter Step 7) Copy table 1 step 8) paste results into table 2.  If those steps are recorded as a macro while manually doing it the first time, they could be repeated over and over assuming you use ctrl-Home, ctrl-end ctrl-D (fill down), ctrl down arrow, right and left arrows and perhaps a mouse click to insert a new column.  We offer assistance to troubleshoot code, not write it from scratch.

Comment: Yeah I know, sorry, I just wanted to see if someone had a solution. Anyway thanks for your time and have a great day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this posting:

https://superuser.com/questions/420635/how-do-i-join-two-worksheets-in-excel-as-i-would-in-sql

You can define your Excel tables as Data Connections and then you can perform SQL commands on them such an OUTER JOIN that will (if I understood your question correctly) provide you the result you require. Regards